# Multi-threading Batch Analysis in WebApplication

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have developed Simple Web-Application and it takes Source path as input parameter and based on Source path , the batch execution takes place in that path and return the output message as success or fail.
The batch execution is Assync so i have used  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3).
Currently execution is taking place but return message am not able to get and am getting null point exception as show below. Please check my code and guide me where am wrong.

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
   <package name="metadataservice" extends="struts-default">



   <action name="Runner" 
            class="org.ms.proj.RunnerAction" 
            method="init">

            <result name="success">/Success.jsp</result>
      </action>

   </package>
</struts>

public class RunnerAction extends ActionSupport {

    public String init()
    {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ActionContext
                .getContext().get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
        String Sourcepath=request.getParameter("srcpath");
        System.out.println("Source Path :"+Sourcepath);
         ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
         Callable<String> callable = new MyExecuorThread(Sourcepath);
         Future<String> future = executor.submit(callable);
         ThreadMonitor addfutur=new ThreadMonitor(future);
         addfutur.CheckThreadReturnValue();
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

My Home.jsp

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Runner" method="post">
<input type="text" value="" name="srcpath"/>
<input type="submit" value="Run">
</form>

public class ThreadMonitor {
    private List<Future<String>> myfutrelist;

    public ThreadMonitor(Future<String> future)
    {
        this.myfutrelist.add(future);
    }

    public void CheckThreadReturnValue()
    {
         for(Future<String> fut : myfutrelist){

                try {
                    System.out.println("Thread Return Method :"+fut.get());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   

            }
    }

public class MyExecuorThread  implements Callable<String>{

    private String srcpath;
    private int exitValue=0;
    public MyExecuorThread(String source)
    {
        this.srcpath=source;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String mylog = "";
        try {
            final File batchFile = new File("D://Runner//bin//runner.bat");
         ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();

        builder.directory(new File(srcpath));
          String[] cmd = { "cmd", "/c",batchFile.getAbsolutePath(),"-Dsonar.login="+"abc","-Dsonar.password="+"chn@27","-X"};

          for (int x = 0; x < cmd.length; x++) {
                System.out.println("Command :" + cmd[x]);   

            }
             builder.command(cmd);
        //  builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
             Process process;
             process = builder.start();
             InputStream is1 = process.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is1);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String line;
             File logfile;
             File logpath=new File(srcpath+File.separator+"LOG");
             if(logpath.isDirectory())
             {
                  logfile=new File(logpath+File.separator+"my.log");

             }
             else
             {
                 logpath.mkdir();
                 logfile=new File(logpath+File.separator+"my.log");
             }
             logfile.createNewFile();

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {                            
                    System.out.println(line);                   
                 mylog+=line+"\n";                  
             }
                exitValue = process.exitValue();
             FileUtils.writeStringToFile(logfile,mylog);           

            process.getInputStream().close();
            process.getOutputStream().close();
            process.getErrorStream().close();
            process.destroy();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(exitValue==0)
        {
            //System.out.println("success");
            return "Analysis Success";
        }
        else
        {
            //System.out.println("failed");
            return "Analysis Failed";
        }

    }
                                         }

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.ms.proj.ThreadMonitor.<init>(ThreadMonitor.java:12)
    org.ms.proj.RunnerAction.init(RunnerAction.java:30)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:891)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1293)
    ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:117)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:108)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1369)
    ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:90)
    ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494)
    ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:458)
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue and how to get return message after batch execution.Please  tell me where am wrong and it will be great help for me thanks anyways.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You used the wrong tags in your question, these arent HTML snippets. Also : read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before you start asking questions ... nobody wants to dig through that much erroneously formatted code.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake .